# Office 365 Small Business LDAP server

Tags: ldap, contacts, office365

I've subscribed to Office 365 Small Business, and I've bought some shiny new VoIP phones that can download contact info from an LDAP server.

Does Office 365 Small Business allow access to the Global Address List using LDAP?

If so, what is the name of the Office 365 LDAP server?

Many thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I assume not, but do you currently have and on-premises Active Directory setup?

Comment: No.  My hope was to have everything provided and managed in the cloud.